# How to convert a SDF molecular structure file to a pandas dataframe with Python?

Tags: python, rdkit

What is the best python tool to convert a SDF file to a structured data frame (pandas.DataFrame). Similar to Molconvert from ChemAxon? SDF can have different datafields for each compound which I would like to have in a dataframe. The 2D or 3D structures can be disregarded.

Comment: Please provide a small example file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easily done with RDKit:

```
from rdkit.Chem import PandasTools

fn = '/mypath/dataset.sdf'

df = PandasTools.LoadSDF(fn, embedProps=True, molColName=None, smilesName='smiles')
```